# Android Studio doesn't find Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

When I click on "run", Genymotion doesn't appear below "Connected Devices".

[image]

When the emulator is running, in the "list of the available Genymotion devices" there isn't an IP address and the status is "Off", even though the emulator is running.

[image]

I've already changed the settings of the ADB in Genymotion (where you put the SDK folder path in the option "use custom Android SDK" tools.)

[image]

I took the path of Android SDK from here:

[image]

I'm doing all of this because I need to use the debug function with Genymotion, since with the normal emulator it take 10 minutes to start.